# determining the null space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to determine the nullspace, but im not quite sure whether or not I do it correct, any help/correction is appreciated.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-3&1\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

$Ax=o$ (the x is a vector but I didn't get Boldface to work)

$x_1+2x_2-3x_3=0$ and $x_4=0$

say $x_2=\alpha$ and $x_3=\beta$

then $x$ (again the vector) $=\alpha\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being scalars

Comment: Choose $x_4 = 0$ and then look at the first row from $A$ to determine free variables.

Comment: Your first vector above (that multiplied by $\;\alpha\;$) isn't in the matrix's kernel. The other one is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure is correct, but there is a mistake ( maybe a typo?).

From :
$x_1+2x_2-3x_3=0$ and $x_4=0$ we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\alpha+3\beta\\\alpha\\\beta\\0
\end{bmatrix}=\alpha
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}+\beta
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$